# Check if value is within one or more ranges, and print all the ranges_IDs containing that value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (Genome_file) with all the genes in a genome (Genome_file$Gene), and for each gene I have the chromosome (Genome_file$Chrom) on which the gene is found and the starting (Genome_file$Start) and ending (Genome_file$End) coordinates in basepairs.

```
Genome_file <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene_1", "Gene_2", "Gene_3", 
"Gene_4", "Gene_5", "Gene_6", "Gene_7", "Gene_8", "Gene_9", "Gene_10"), 
Chrom = c("Chr_01", "Chr_01", "Chr_01", "Chr_01", "Chr_01", "Chr_04", 
"Chr_04", "Chr_04", "Chr_04", "Chr_04"), Start = c(1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 
4000L, 5000L, 1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 4000L, 5000L), End = c(1900L, 2900L, 
3900L, 4900L, 5900L, 1900L, 2900L, 3900L, 4900L, 5900L)), .Names = 
c("Gene", "Chrom", "Start", "End"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = 
"data.frame")

>Genome_file
Gene      Chrom   Start  End
Gene_1    Chr_01  1000   1900
Gene_2    Chr_01  2000   2900
Gene_3    Chr_01  3000   3900
Gene_4    Chr_01  4000   4900
Gene_5    Chr_01  5000   5900
Gene_6    Chr_04  1000   1900
Gene_7    Chr_04  2000   2900
Gene_8    Chr_04  3000   3900
Gene_9    Chr_04  4000   4900
Gene_10   Chr_04  5000   5900
```

In another dataframe (QTLs), I have a list of QTL intervals that have been found for that genome across several publications. For each QTL, the dataframe reports an ID (QTLs$QTL_ID), the starting position of the QTL interval (QTL$Start), the ending position of the QTL interval (QTL$End), and the chromosome on which the QTL is found (QTL$Chrom). Some QTLs overlap with each other as they come from different publications and have been mapped by independent research efforts.

```
QTLs <- structure(list(QTL_ID = c("QTL_1", "QTL_2", "QTL_3", "QTL_4", 
"QTL_5"), Chrom = c("Chr_01", "Chr_01", "Chr_01", "Chr_03", "Chr_04"), 
Start = c(100L, 100L, 4000L, 7000L, 3000L), End = c(1950L, 3950L, 4950L, 
8000L, 4900L)), .Names = c("QTL_ID", "Chrom", "Start", "End"), row.names = 
c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

> QTLs
QTL_ID  Chrom    Start  End
QTL_1   Chr_01   100    1950
QTL_2   Chr_01   100    3950
QTL_3   Chr_01   4000   4950
QTL_4   Chr_03   7000   8000
QTL_5   Chr_04   3000   4900
```

Now, what I would like to do is to check whether the starting position of each gene in the genome file falls in any QTL interval in the QTL dataframe. Whenever a gene falls in a QTL, I would like to print the QTL_ID in a new column of the Genome_file (let's call this column "QTL"). In the case a gene is comprised within more than one QTL interval, I would like all the IDs of the QTLs within which the gene is comprised to be printed in the new "QTL" column, possibly separated by a semicolon (;).

Desired output:

```
#Gene    Chrom    Start  End    QTL
#Gene_1  Chr_01   1000   1900   QTL_1;QTL_2
#Gene_2  Chr_01   2000   2900   QTL_2
#Gene_3  Chr_01   3000   3900   QTL_2
#Gene_4  Chr_01   4000   4900   QTL_3
#Gene_5  Chr_01   5000   5900            
#Gene_6  Chr_04   1000   1900            
#Gene_7  Chr_04   2000   2900            
#Gene_8  Chr_04   3000   3900   QTL_5
#Gene_9  Chr_04   4000   4900   QTL_5
#Gene_10 Chr_04   5000   5900
```

So far I have been able to apply the following function to print the first QTL that is found to comprise a specific gene. However, I cannot figure out how to print all the QTLs that comprise a certain gene, separated by semicolon (;).

The function that I have tried:

```
library(magrittr)

# get a list of vectors where each item is whether a gene's start in 
Genome_file is comprised in a QTL in QTLs dataframe
Positionok  <- lapply(Genome_file$Gene_Start_bp, function(z) z >= 
QTLs$bp_Start_1LOD & z <= QTLs$bp_End_1LOD)

# another list of logical vectors indicating whether gene's chromosome 
matches the QTL chromosome
Chromok  <- lapply(Genome_file$Chrom, function(z) z== QTLs$Chrom)

# combine the two list and use the combined vectors as an index on 
Genome_file$QTL
Genome_file$QTL <- lapply(1:nrow(Genome_file), function(i) {
QTLs$QTL_ID[ Positionok[[i]] & Chromok[[i]]  ]
}) %>% 

# replace zero length strings with NA values
sapply(function(QTLs) ifelse(length(QTLs) == 0, NA, QTLs))
```

Any help would be really appreciated! I am stucked and I do not know how to go on in my work! Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [`genomicRanges` package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html), it should make it easier for you to manipulate genomic intervals. Then there is `findOverlaps` function that should suit you. Alternatively, you can check `data.table::foverlaps` function